# What does tcpdump: pcap_loop: truncated dump file; tried to read 1899 captured bytes, only got 1880 mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, macos-catalina, tcpdump

I can't see any other question that asks the same thing as mine. I want to know what `tcpdump: pcap_loop: truncated dump file; tried to read 1899 captured bytes, only got 1880` means. I received it when I was trying to save the output of `tcpdump -x /path/to/file`. I used macOS's Wireless Diagnostics to capture packets and store it in a .pcap file and now when I run `tcpdump -x /path/to/file`, I get the message `tcpdump: pcap_loop: truncated dump file; tried to read 1899 captured bytes, only got 1880`. Did I do something wrong? Do I need to do anything differently? I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.4 if it helps. All help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `-U` or `-l` options as documented in the man page:

```
-l
Make stdout line buffered. Useful if you want to see the data 
while capturing it. E.g.,
  tcpdump -l | tee dat
  or
  tcpdump -l > dat & tail -f dat

Note that on Windows,``line buffered'' means ``unbuffered'', 
so that WinDump will write each character individually if -l
is specified.


-U is similar to -l in its behavior, but it will cause output
to be ``packet-buffered'', so that the output is written to 
stdout at the end of each packet rather than at the end of 
each line; this is buffered on all platforms, including 
Windows.
```

Source https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html